# BSOD, MBR corrupt, tried to fix using Testdisk on Linux dual boot, now nothing works

Tags: boot, centos, grub, mbr, testdisk

The short story is I received a BSOD from a Windows program. I then couldn't boot Windows. My system is set up with GRUB to dual boot into CentOS, so I booted into CentOS and attempted to fix the MBR using TestDisk. Now I cannot boot into either OS, nor do I see GRUB. I am able to view files using TestDisk from a LiveCD so I can see they are still there. Below is the output from a [bootinfoscript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and a fdisk -l, running from Fedora LiveCD.

Currently when I boot to the hard drive I get a "Hard Drive Error" prompt, that is all.

sdd is the hard drive that contains the Windows and Linux partitions. It says GRUB is installed but I am not booting to it. I have tried to "Analyse" and a "Deeper Search" using testdisk and I forget the exact error but it could not come up with a table.

The table looks fine though according to the bootinfoscript.

Please, how can I fix this? There must be a way!

edit: I have tried booting the Windows 7 install disk and Repair mode does not see its partition. Additinoally CentOS repair mode does not see its partition.

bootinfoscript:

```
      Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Grub Legacy (v0.97) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc and looks on boot 
    drive #1 in partition #3 for /grub/stage2 and /grub/grub.conf.
 => Testdisk is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdd.
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sde.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Grub Legacy
    Boot sector info:  Grub Legacy (v0.97) is installed in the boot sector 
                       of sdc1 and looks at sector 1 on boot drive #119 for 
                       the stage2 file.  A stage2 file is at this location on 
                       /dev/sdd.  Stage2 looks on the same partition for 
                       /grub/stage2. No errors found in the Boot Parameter 
                       Block.
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
Failed to read last sector (1953534081): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
Failed to read last sector (1953534081): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

sdd1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Grub Legacy
    Boot sector info:  Grub Legacy (v0.97) is installed in the boot sector 
                       of sdd1 and looks at sector 1 on boot drive #119 for 
                       the stage2 file.  A stage2 file is at this location on 
                       /dev/sdd.  Stage2 looks on the same partition for 
                       /grub/stage2. No errors found in the Boot Parameter 
                       Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sdd2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Grub Legacy
    Boot sector info:  Grub Legacy (v0.97) is installed in the boot sector 
                       of sdd2 and looks at sector 1 on boot drive #119 for 
                       the stage2 file.  A stage2 file is at this location on 
                       /dev/sdd.  Stage2 looks on the same partition for 
                       /grub/stage2. No errors found in the Boot Parameter 
                       Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdd3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub Legacy
    Boot sector info:  Grub Legacy (v) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdd3 and looks at sector 977307854 of the same hard 
                       drive for the stage2 file, but no stage2 files can be 
                       found at this location.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/menu.lst /grub/grub.conf

sdd4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub Legacy
    Boot sector info:  Grub Legacy (v0.97) is installed in the boot sector 
                       of sdd4 and looks at sector 977306630 of the same hard 
                       drive for the stage2 file.  A stage2 file is at this 
                       location on /dev/sdd.  Stage2 looks on partition #3 
                       for /grub/grub.conf.

sdd5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  Grub Legacy
    Boot sector info:  Grub Legacy (v0.97) is installed in the boot sector 
                       of sdd5 and looks at sector 977307806 of the same hard 
                       drive for the stage2 file.  A stage2 file is at this 
                       location on /dev/sdd.  Stage2 looks on partition #3 
                       for /grub/grub.conf.

sde1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sde1 has 
                       625137663 sectors, but according to the info from 
                       fdisk, it has 625151361 sectors.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

vg_mikenix-lv_root': ___________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
Failed to read last sector (1953534081): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
Failed to read last sector (1953534081): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x454c4946  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 48  usa_count: 2: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x1003800010004) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x454c4946  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 48  usa_count: 2: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x1003800010004) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

vg_mikenix-lv_home': ___________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
Failed to read last sector (1953534081): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
Failed to read last sector (1953534081): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x454c4946  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 48  usa_count: 2: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x1003800010004) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x454c4946  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 48  usa_count: 2: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x1003800010004) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

vg_mikenix-lv_swap': ___________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
Failed to read last sector (1953534081): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
Failed to read last sector (1953534081): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x454c4946  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 48  usa_count: 2: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x1003800010004) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x454c4946  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 48  usa_count: 2: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x1003800010004) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                  63   625,140,399   625,140,337  42 SFS


Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1               2,048 1,953,536,129 1,953,534,082   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS

/dev/sdc1 ends after the last sector of /dev/sdc

Drive: sdd _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdd1    *          2,048       211,679       209,632   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sdd2             206,848   976,767,119   976,560,272   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sdd3         976,764,928   977,788,927     1,024,000  83 Linux
/dev/sdd4         977,788,928 1,953,525,167   975,736,240   5 Extended
/dev/sdd5         977,790,976 1,953,523,711   975,732,736  8e Linux LVM

/dev/sdd1 overlaps with /dev/sdd2
/dev/sdd2 overlaps with /dev/sdd3

Drive: sde _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sde: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sde1    *          2,048   625,153,409   625,151,362   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS

/dev/sde1 ends after the last sector of /dev/sde

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop1                                              DM_snapshot_cow 
/dev/loop2                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop3       b39d6418-8f98-4350-a48a-e70b0dd203f9   ext4       _Fedora-17-x86_6
/dev/mapper/live-osimg-min b39d6418-8f98-4350-a48a-e70b0dd203f9   ext4       _Fedora-17-x86_6
/dev/mapper/live-rw b39d6418-8f98-4350-a48a-e70b0dd203f9   ext4       _Fedora-17-x86_6
/dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_home 52e59386-1ea4-4dd0-b94b-6b8dbe389358   ext4       
/dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_root 563ab476-602e-4c05-abb7-33b44a12d9fb   ext4       
/dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_swap 342be5e7-dd8b-44e5-9e9f-c705e385ad4e   swap       
/dev/sdc1        80C2F69090FA0800                       ntfs       New Volume
/dev/sdd1        80C2F69090FA0800                       ntfs       System Reserved
/dev/sdd2        80C2F69090FA0800                       ntfs       
/dev/sdd3        34bfd48b-c8ca-41f3-a5cb-aa9991e98f2d   ext4       
/dev/sdd5        GxpmvW-powX-BiJ1-qaXB-SH9r-fuV3-WUeBef LVM2_member 
/dev/sde1        EE524F21524EEDC1                       ntfs       
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Fedora-17-x86_64-Live-Desktop.is

========================= "ls -R /dev/mapper/" output: =========================

/dev/mapper:
control
live-osimg-min
live-rw
vg_mikenix-lv_home
vg_mikenix-lv_root
vg_mikenix-lv_swap

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/mapper/live-rw /                        ext4       (rw,noatime,seclabel,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
/dev/sr0         /run/initramfs/live      iso9660    (ro,relatime)


============================= sdd3/grub/grub.conf: =============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,2)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_root
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sdd
default=2
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,2)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.x86_64)
    root (hd0,2)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_mikenix/lv_swap rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_mikenix/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.x86_64.img
title CentOS (2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64)
    root (hd0,2)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_mikenix/lv_swap rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_mikenix/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64.img
title Windows 7
    rootnoverify (hd0,0)
    chainloader +1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdd3: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

 466.016604424 = 500.381518848  grub/grub.conf                                 1
 466.016604424 = 500.381518848  grub/menu.lst                                  1
 466.016795158 = 500.381723648  grub/stage2                                    1
 465.821786880 = 500.172335104  initramfs-2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.x86_64.img        2
 465.790484428 = 500.138724352  initramfs-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64.img            2
 465.826546669 = 500.177445888  initrd-2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.x86_64kdump.img      1
 465.795757294 = 500.144386048  initrd-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64kdump.img          1
 465.804494858 = 500.153767936  vmlinuz-2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.x86_64              1
 465.773245811 = 500.120214528  vmlinuz-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64                  1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on vg_mikenix-lv_root'


Unknown BootLoader on vg_mikenix-lv_home'


Unknown BootLoader on vg_mikenix-lv_swap'



========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdb 

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

ls: reading directory sdd2/: Input/output error
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
hexdump: /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_root': No such file or directory
hexdump: stdin: Bad file descriptor
hexdump: /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_root': No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_root': Bad file descriptor
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
hexdump: /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_home': No such file or directory
hexdump: stdin: Bad file descriptor
hexdump: /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_home': No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_home': Bad file descriptor
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
hexdump: /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_swap': No such file or directory
hexdump: stdin: Bad file descriptor
hexdump: /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_swap': No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_swap': Bad file descriptor
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x48c044ea

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63   625140399   312570168+  42  SFS

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x75f7e06d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  1953536129   976767041    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x812f5830

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *        2048      211679      104816    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdd2          206848   976767119   488280136    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdd3       976764928   977788927      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sdd4       977788928  1953525167   487868120    5  Extended
/dev/sdd5       977790976  1953523711   487866368   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sde: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x14a014a0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1   *        2048   625153409   312575681    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/mapper/live-rw: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders, total 8388608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/live-osimg-min: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders, total 8388608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders, total 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_home: 439.6 GB, 439609196544 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 53446 cylinders, total 858611712 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_mikenix-lv_swap: 6274 MB, 6274678784 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 762 cylinders, total 12255232 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Comment: Have you tried running boot-repair?

Comment: I have not. I can try this evening. I see it is a Ubuntu utility. If there are any tricks or specific usage for it please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Not really, you can tinker with the settings a bit, but usually the default settings are enough. If you want there is also a live CD available ;)

Comment: It might be worth trying to boot directly into your Linux partition with [Super Grub Disc 2](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) to see that it isn't corrupted - the bootinfoscript seems to think they are (though I could be reading it wrong).  It should auto detect your systems and let you try to get in.  Did you change anything recently before this (SATA mode, hardware, new hdd, etc.)?  It probably goes without saying, but if you have the ability to back up your goodies, that would probably be wise.

Comment: I did try using the Super Grub Disc 2 yesterday. I tried all the options and it would just go to a black screen and do nothing. I have not made any recent changes to hardware. The progam I ran that gave me a BSOD was CPU-Z. It doesn't make sense :-|

Comment: boot-repair did not work. It was indefinitely searching for partitions. I just bought a new hard drive. Looks like I am going to reinstall Windows, Linux and transfer over. Thank you both for the help.

Comment: Possibly too late / not possible but in certain situations you could try using spinrite http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm.

Answer (score 0):

The CentOS livecd can be used to reinstall Grub and fix your MBR. Details on this approach are on the CentOS wiki at http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/ReinstallGRUB